# Cloud Firestore permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I have the following permissions configured in my Cloud Firestore, but I'm having some problems with the visualization of my items.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /pages/{pageid} {

      // Returns true if the user is logged        
      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }

      // Returns true if the logged user is admin
      function isAdmin() {
        return isSignedIn()
            && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
      }

      // Returns true if the requested page has published marked as true (or should, at least :( )
      function isPublished() {
        return resource.data.published == true;
      }

      allow read: if isPublished() || isAdmin();
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

I can't make the `isPublished()` to work properly. The content is not being shown as it should be. the `isAdmin()` works properly.

My data has the property `published` configured as `boolean` as expected and all of them but one is checked as `true`. Nothing is shown and this error appears in the browser:

```
core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

By the way, my code is based on the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#evaluating_constraints_on_queries

Here is an example of the data I'm trying to read from:
[image]

And the constructor of my Angular Service getting a list of the pages:

```
constructor(
  public afs: AngularFirestore) {   

    this.pagesCollection = this.afs.collection('pages', ref => ref.orderBy('order', 'asc'));

    this.pages = this.pagesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Page;
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        })
      })
    );
}

getPages(){
  return this.pages;   
}
```

Comment: At first glance the rules look fine. Can you add: 1) the document you are trying to read? 2) the minimal code that you can get the error with?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen picture and code are added

Comment: Does it matter for the `resource.data` if I'm trying to `get` or `list`?

Comment: Two more informations:
If I change the line `allow read: if isPublished() || isAdmin();` for `allow read;` it works.
I used the simulator and it works, but not with my code, for some random reason. I think is something related to my code is trying to list, in the simulator I used the `get` to get a specific data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to read all documents, which your rules do not allow. Keep in mind that security rules don't filter documents. They merely ensure that the read operation matches the rules, which in your case it doesn't.

This means you'll need to replicate the logic from your rule in your query, by only requesting published documents:

```
ref.where('published', '==', true).orderBy('order', 'asc')
```

For more on this, see:

- the Firebase [documentation on securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query)
- [episode 6 in the Getting to know Cloud Firestore video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw)

Comment: Ok, that part of 'not filtering' I didn't know. So, depending on the access level, I'll need to add or not the `.where('published', '==', true)` part.

Comment: Or it needs to be always added to my code? Because if yes, how to I filter unpublished stories to show only for admins/owners?

Comment: Your query needs to meet your rules. That's the hard constraint here. Since your rules `allow read: if isPublished() || isAdmin()`, the query will always need to be either of those. So the `.where('published', '==', true)` needs to be there for non-administrators only.

Comment: So, should I then first test the `isAdmin()` and then the `isPublished()`, right? This way I first check if the user is an admin and, in case he is one, I don't enter on the isPublished case.

Comment: There is no difference in the order of the clauses in an or expression. The result for `isAdmin() || isPublished()` is the same as for `isPublished() || isAdmin()`. I personally find the first one easier to read, because the broader clause comes first.